# how to create css shapes X which has to be background inside?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I need to create a X shape using css3 where the background images and text should be placed inside it. The width and height of the X shape would be 300px each. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? You may want to provide an image of what you want to clarify.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to make a mask for your image. http://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: this might help you http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html

Comment: Thanks. I have tried just css3 shapes which didn't work. 
@chipChocolate.py can you please tell me how this svn works if i have to increase the width and height of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using `svg`'s `mask`.

You can change the `width` and `height` by changing the `#container`'s `width` and `height`.

```css
#container {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 80 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
      <mask id="m" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="100">
        <path d="M0,0 h15 l25,38 l25,-38 h15 l-32,50 l32,50 h-15 l-25,-38 l-25,38 h-15 l32,-50" fill="white" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <image mask="url(#m)" width="80" height="100" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/80/100" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

Also, possible using `pattern`.

```css
#container {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 80 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="p" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="100">
        <image mask="url(#m)" width="80" height="100" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/80/100" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M0,0 h15 l25,38 l25,-38 h15 l-32,50 l32,50 h-15 l-25,-38 l-25,38 h-15 l32,-50" fill="url(#p)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Wrapping the text inside a shape would be possible when browsers implement the [`shape-inside`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes-2/#shape-inside-property) property. Currently it is only [supported on `-webkit-` browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=shape-inside) and must not be used.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to create an image mask.

**Please note**, I'm not sure this is the best option due to [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path), but this is working for chrome presently using the **-webkit-** prefix for me.

However, since IE doesn't support this, I will leave this here as **an additional, chrome-only solution**.

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 0% 20%, 30% 50%, 0% 80%, 20% 100%, 50% 70%, 80% 100%, 100% 80%, 70% 50%, 100% 20%, 80% 0%, 50% 30%);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 0% 20%, 30% 50%, 0% 80%, 20% 100%, 50% 70%, 80% 100%, 100% 80%, 70% 50%, 100% 20%, 80% 0%, 50% 30%);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt="" />
```